# Python formatting print

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I'm having some formatting issues with my call to print function. For lack of knowledge of better ways to format, i've ended up with an issue. [here is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbp8O.png)

However the actual result of my print returns this.

[image: My print]

```
def tupleMaker(inputString):
    s1 = inputString.split()

    # Adding the surname at the end of the string
    s2 = [s1[len(s1) - 1]]

    # Number of other names(no surname)
    global noOfNames
    noOfNames = len(s1) - 4

    # Adding all the other names
    for i in range(noOfNames):
        s2.append((s1[i + 3]))

    # Adding the Reg number
    s2.append(s1[0])

    # Adding the Degree scheme
    s2.append(s1[2])

    # Adding the year
    s2.append("Year " + s1[1])

    # Making it a tuple
    t = ()
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        t = t + (s2[i],)
    return t


def formatting(t):

    s1 = ""

    for i in range(len(t)):
        s1 += t[i]
        if (i == 0):
            s1 += ", "
        elif (i == len(t) - 4):
            s1 += "        "
        else:
            s1 += " "

    #print(t[0] + ", ", end="")
    #for i in range(noOfNames):
        #print (t[i+1], end= " ")

    #print(format(t[1+noOfNames], "<32s"))
    #print(format(thenames, "<32d") + format(regNo, "<7d") + format(degScheme, ">6s") + format(year, ">1s")
    print("")
    print(s1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at using pythons built in string.format() function a small tutorial is located here: https://pyformat.info/